# jQuery getJSON save result into variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I use getJSON to request a JSON from my website. It works great, but I need to save the output into another variable, like this:

```
var myjson= $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:8080/horizon-update", function(json) {

                 });
```

I need to save the result into `myjson` but it seems this syntax is not correct. Any ideas?

Comment: Simply remove `var myjson= `

Comment: Have a look at [How to return the response from an AJAX call from a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call-from-a-function) -- at least it should give you the right idea how to solve the problem. The syntax btw is valid, it just does not do what you want it to.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can't get value when calling `getJSON`, only after response.

```
var myjson;
$.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:8080/horizon-update", function(json){
    myjson = json;
});
```

Comment: The problem with this is that `var myjson` is not available on the very next line due to timing issues.

Comment: @JanDvorak Yes, request executes asynchronously, if you need `json` data to proceed, you should call other code after setting `myjson` variable. As solution it could be like 'callbackFuncWithData' from Ravi answer OR just call another function.

Comment: Once you do that, there's really no reason to keep `myjson` declared outside. Just pass it to the callback as an argument.

Comment: @JanDvorak Sometimes it's required, for example when you using client filtering. It depends on your app logic.

Answer (score 25):

$.getJSon expects a callback functions either you pass it to the callback function or in callback function assign it to global variale.

```
var globalJsonVar;

    $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:8080/horizon-update", function(json){
               //do some thing with json  or assign global variable to incoming json. 
                globalJsonVar=json;
          });
```

IMO  best is to call the callback function. which is nicer to eyes, readability aspects.

```
$.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:8080/horizon-update", callbackFuncWithData);

function callbackFuncWithData(data)
{
 // do some thing with data 
}
```

Comment: i dont think the first solution will works. .getJSON is asynchronous so you wont be able to reach any outside variable. What you need to do is set async:false in low level ajax

Comment: @lngs: No, it will work. The callback function is a *closure* and has access to all variables defined in higher scopes. You still have to be careful though *when* to access the variable, i.e. you cannot access it immediately after you made the call to `$.getJSON`. In that case you really would have to make a synchronous request.

Comment: So how could you know when is ajax call finished and how big is response data? You still need to use callback function to do it.

Comment: Yes, how can you know *when* you can access the data?