# Search Json Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, json

I got a json array like below:

```
[
    {"value":"uk-icon-adjust","title":"Adjust","url":"#", "text":""},
    {"value":"uk-icon-adn","title":"Adn","url":"#", "text":""},
    {"value":"uk-icon-align-center","title":"Align center","url":"#", "text":""},
    {"value":"uk-icon-align-justify","title":"Align justify","url":"#", "text":""},
    {"value":"uk-icon-align-left","title":"Align left","url":"#", "text":""}
]
```

I want to search this json array for specific titles. But the problem is, that I want to search with a Regex.
e.g: sb searchs for "ad" -> the function should return the first two json strings (Adjust and Adn).

I have no idea, now to setup a javascript function which can achieve this.

Some ideas?

Comment: hi, try the library I've created for exactly this purpose at http://www.json.spiritway.co

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
var array = [
    {"value":"uk-icon-adjust","title":"Adjust","url":"#", "text":""},
    {"value":"uk-icon-adn","title":"Adn","url":"#", "text":""},
    {"value":"uk-icon-align-center","title":"Align center","url":"#", "text":""},
    {"value":"uk-icon-align-justify","title":"Align justify","url":"#", "text":""},
    {"value":"uk-icon-align-left","title":"Align left","url":"#", "text":""}
  ],
  searchString = 'ad',
  searchRegExp = new RegExp(searchString , 'i'); // 'i' makes the RegExp ignore case

var result = array.filter(function(e){ // Filter out any items that don't pass the
    return searchRegExp.test(e.title); //  RegExp test.
});
```

Result:

```
[
    {"value":"uk-icon-adjust","title":"Adjust","url":"#","text":""},
    {"value":"uk-icon-adn","title":"Adn","url":"#","text":""}
]
```

If you *only* want an array of titles, you can then map the result, like this:

```
var titles = result.map(function(e){
    return e.title;
});
```

Titles:

```
["Adjust", "Adn"]
```

You'll want to do this mapping *after* filtering the array, for efficiency. This way you'll only have to iterate over the filtered result, instead of first iterating over **all** items to get the titles, then iterating over **all** of them again to filter them.

Of course, this can be combined with the filtering:

```
var result = array.filter(function(e){
    return searchRegExp.test(e.title);
}).map(function(e){
    return e.title;
});
```

Please keep in mind that both [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) as [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) Aren't supported in IE 8 or lower. However, the pages I linked to do have some polyfills to make these functions work in older versions of IE.

Comment: how about, if I have the json array to search in a extern json file? I tried it this way:
`var array = $.getJSON(url);`
but then the filter function not works?

Comment: @Smeaven: That's because `getJSON` is asynchronous. [See this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764844/jquery-getjson-save-result-into-variable)

Answer (score 3):

That's an native Object. You can do it this way though, by first creating an Array of titles by using `Array.map` and then filter them using `Array.filter`

```
var titles = obj.filter(function(o){
   return /^ad/i.test(o.title);
}).map(function(o){ return o.title; });
```

Comment: It'd be more efficient to use `filter` before `map`.

Comment: @Cerbrus I think it's *micro-optimization*. I've not heard it before. Would love to see links stating so. Honestly

Comment: Assume you have an array of 100 items: Map->Filter iterates over 100 items twice, always resulting in 200 iterations.

Filter->Map first iterates (filters) over 100 items, then iterates over the remaining items. More often than not, this will result in less than 200 iterations.

Just because something is a _"micro-optimization"_ doesn't mean it's a bad idea to think about what your code is actually doing on what kind of data.

Answer (score 2):

Amit Joki answer is *the* answer.
If you don't want to use map(), you could also try:

```
var json = [
    {"value":"uk-icon-adjust","title":"Adjust","url":"#", "text":""},
    {"value":"uk-icon-adn","title":"Adn","url":"#", "text":""},
    {"value":"uk-icon-align-center","title":"Align center","url":"#", "text":""},
    {"value":"uk-icon-align-justify","title":"Align justify","url":"#", "text":""},
    {"value":"uk-icon-align-left","title":"Align left","url":"#", "text":""}
];

function search(array, re) {
    var regexp = new RegExp(re, 'gi');
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        return array[i].title.match(regexp);
    }
    throw "Couldn't find object like " + re;
}

console.info(search(json, 'ad'));
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `obj.map`.

Comment: @Cerbrus: There is if `obj` is an Array.

Comment: @MarcoS: to any `array`. In JavaScript, when you're talking about objects, You generally mean the generic JS object type.