# Stock getJSON data in a global var but later says its undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, undefined, getjson

So I want to get data using $.getJSON and stock it in a variable to use it later. Even if I declared the variable 'subcount' before the $.getJSON, I get it as a undefined when I actually want to do something with it. My code looks like this:

```
function loadSubs() {
        channel_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id="+channelId+"&key="+key;

            var subcount;

            $.getJSON(channel_url, function(data) {
                subcount = data.items[0].statistics.subscriberCount;
                console.log("In scope: "+subcount);
            });

        console.log("Out of scope: "+subcount);
        do_something_with_data();
        }
```

The console gives me

```
 Out of scope: undefined
 In scope: 1364189
```

It seems like when it's coming out of the getJSON scope, the variable returns to its undefined state. I tried to initialize it with

```
subcount = '';
```

To make it global, but it does the same thing, instead of getting undefined, I get a blank string. I also think that the fact that the out-of-scope log comes first is part of the problem.

Am I missing something? If so, can you explain? Is there another way to do this?

Thanks

EDIT: I declared 'subcount' based on this answer on a different thread
[jQuery getJSON save result into variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764844/jquery-getjson-save-result-into-variable)

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of async processing.

Comment: The important thing to notice is that it logs `Out of scope` *first*. In other words it is logging that value before you have set it.  This pattern doesn't work and the answer at the linked question is very misleading.

Comment: Thank you Mark, I will continue my research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this thread: [Is it possible to set async:false to $.getJSON call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765411/is-it-possible-to-set-asyncfalse-to-getjson-call)

I change the $.getJSON to $.ajax and put async:false

```
function get_subcount(chan_url) {
            var subcount;
            $.ajax({
                url:chan_url,
                datatype:'json',
                async:false,
                success: function(data) {
                subcount = data.items[0].statistics.subscriberCount;
                }
            });
            return subcount
        }
```

Now I get the same answer in my previous 'In scope' and 'Out of scope'