# jQuery return $.getJSON value

Tags: jquery

How can I save "data" into "result"?

Here's the code:

```js
function GetCoordinates(adres) {
  var result = "";
  jQuery.getJSON('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+adres+'&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyBxhmTCArabnNgXc6IGM7EEpgohO_mECWs',function(data) {
  result = data.results[0].geometry.location["lat"] + ',' + data.results[0].geometry.location["lng"];
  });
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery getJSON save result into variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764844/jquery-getjson-save-result-into-variable)

Answer (score 1):

You're adding value to result from an anonymous function, so when you call `function(data)`, it is adding value to `result`, but in the parent function, it is returning `result` before it is ready.

Unfortunately, there is no way to return value from an event listener.

I still cleaned your code though:

```js
function GetCoordinates(adres) {
  var result = "";
  $.getJSON(`https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${adres}&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyBxhmTCArabnNgXc6IGM7EEpgohO_mECWs`, (data) => { 
    result = data.results[0].geometry.location["lat"] + "," + data.results[0].geometry.location["lng"];
  });
  return result;
}
```